# How to negate a parameter in search request in Swagger?

Tags: api, swagger

I am writing my first Swagger spec for a search endpoint and wondering if there is a simple way to negate a search parameter.

Here is the yml for searching by brand:

```
properties:
  brand:
    description: The magazine that produced the original article
    type: string
```

I would also like our users to be able to search by excluding a brand (eg either "from [brand]" or "not from [brand]".  Is there a more graceful approach than creating duplicate properties for each parameter (eg, both `brand` and `notBrand`)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following.  If you are using query parameters for the search endpoint (which is probably smart), you should consider having a querystring parameter like such:

```
    - name: brand
      in: query
      type: array
      items:
        type: string
```

You can have another query parameter for `excludes` which follows the same syntax.  Be sure to set the `collectionFormat` depending on how your API will parse the query string, since arrays are simply not standardized across frameworks.  Read [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#fixed-fields-7) for more details.